# Flutter firebase_messaging - PushNotification does not appear in Status bar

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

With the following code

```
  Future<String?> initFirebaseAndGetToken() async {
await Firebase.initializeApp();

FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
  alert: true,
  announcement: false,
  badge: true,
  carPlay: false,
  criticalAlert: false,
  provisional: false,
  sound: true,
);

if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
  print('User granted permission');
} else if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
  print('User granted provisional permission');
} else {
  print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
}

return messaging.getToken();
```

}

I get the token but when I send a message it just get

```
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(20206): broadcast received for message

W/FirebaseMessaging(20206): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing

W/FirebaseMessaging(20206): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
```

in the Console but the message does not appear in the Android Phones statusbar.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When the app is in the foreground messages are not shown. You have to handle them separately. More about [fcm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_messages)